# OG Meta tags not working as intended

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-social-plugins

I see the OG Meta tags in the source of the rendered homepage of my site.
I see the correct image/location displayed in the code.

But, when I hit the LIKE button > the displayed image on the Facebook page is incorrect.

Also, I have individual settings for "Liking" individual products on our site.  The settings look to be setup correctly.  But I cannot get the OG Meta tags to show in the rendered HTML.

Thanks

Comment: Show us your like button code and the URL of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is using a cache on the OG data. Put your URL in this form https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug 
It will clear Facebook's cache.